# How to detect numbers written in "calculator" font

Tags: android, firebase, tensorflow, firebase-mlkit

I'm trying to recognise numbers written on a calculator or similar electronic device. However Firebase ML has a very good model for reading regular fonts and numbers, but is unable to read numbers written in "calculator" font.
[image]

I've been thinking to [use custom model](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/custom-models) from eg. [TensorFlow](https://tfhub.dev/s?module-type=text-embedding,text-classification,text-generation,text-language-model,text-question-answering,text-retrieval-question-answering), however it look slike they can be used for image labelling, not text recognition! Any ideas how to read those numbers? Should be easy right?

Comment: This is not supported in ML Kit for now, and we are working on this.

Comment: Any estimates you can provide, like this year, this Q1?

Comment: We hope to provide support in Q2, but it depends on if we can boost the quality of our existing model. It is not there where we want it just yet.